# find the sum of amount between 2 dates

Tags: mysql

I m having a table payment which contains id,amount,date.
I need to calculate the total amount between 2 dates.. 
I have a form in which user enters the start date and end date..I need to calculate the total amount which is between the 2 dates..

### **QUERY**

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT sum(amount) 
                       FROM payment 
                       WHERE (date BETWEEN '$date' and '$date1')");
I m getting the wrong sum..
```

here is the records it is fetching from database

Total Amount Contributed: 600

```
Membership No |  Month    |  Date        |  Amount
--------------+-----------+--------------+-----------
14015         |  October  | 2014-09-13   |   600
14017         |  October  | 2014-09-14   |   400
14013         |  October  | 2014-09-17   |   100
14015         |  November | 2014-09-17   |   500
```

Comment: What are the values of $date and $date1?

Comment: it is entered in the form using date field

Comment: @user3675208 he has asked for the values you have tested for example? give a demo what date you have tested for

Comment: may i know the datatype of your date field in database

Comment: the mistake is in the date format

Comment: the date is between 2014-09-13 to 2014-09-17

Comment: Cast the Date to nvarchar and check it?

Comment: i have chaged it to varchar but the result is same

Comment: @user3675208 : try `date BETWEEN '".$date."' and '".$date1."'`

Comment: you can use date >= <some-start-date> AND date <= <some-end-date>

Comment: i have to enter start and end date in the php form

Comment: it will retrieve the records between the 2 dates

Comment: what is the format and type of php variable `$date`

Comment: format is mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: type is varchar in the table.. And input type is date

Answer (score 0):

You can try formatting your date variables like --`

```
  $date="13-09-2014";
    $date1="17-09-2014";

    $date=date_format ( $date, 'Y-m-d' );
    $date1=date_format ( $date1, 'Y-m-d' );

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT sum(amount) 
                       FROM payment 
                       WHERE (date BETWEEN '$date' and '$date1')");
```

`

Answer (score 0):

### QUERY-

```
        SELECT sum(amount) FROM payment WHERE date BETWEEN  
        STR_TO_DATE('$date','%m/%d/%Y') 
        and 
        STR_TO_DATE('$date1','%m/%d/%Y')
```

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0feeb/4)

Answer (score 0):

Make input format as "dd MMM yyyy"

```
"SELECT sum(amount) 
                   FROM payment 
                   WHERE (cast(date as nvarchar(12) BETWEEN '$date' and '$date1')"
```

or

```
"SELECT sum(amount) 
                   FROM payment 
                   WHERE (convert(nvarchar(12),date,106) BETWEEN '$date' and '$date1')"
```